# Real part of complex number?

Tags: r

I'm just learning R, so please forgive what I'm sure is a very elementary question.  How do I take the real part of a complex number?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you read the help file for `complex` (`?complex`), you will see a number of functions for performing  complex arithmetic. The details clearly state

> The functions `Re`, `Im`, `Mod`, `Arg` and `Conj` have their usual interpretation as returning the real part, imaginary part, modulus, argument and complex conjugate for complex values.

Therefore

Use `Re`:

```
Re(1+2i)
# 1
```

For the imaginary part:

```
Im(1+2i)
# 2
```

`?complex` will list other useful functions.

Answer (score 7):

```
Re(z)
```

and

```
Im(z)
```

would be the functions you're looking for.

See also http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2009/12/18/using-complex-numbers-in-r/

Comment: Ah ha!  I guessed "re", but got "No documentation for ‘re’ in specified packages and libraries".  I never occurred to me I just had the wrong case!