# how to get real valule in R

Tags: python, r

I have some python code I'd like to convert to R

`a` here is a numpy_array.

```
 a=[1.80609382e+11+0.00000000e+00j,1.74874507e+11+3.22606828e-06j]
 a[0].real
 # output 180609381652.28638 (this is what i am looking for in R)
```

How can I do this with R?

Comment: Surely a duplicate of [Real part of complex number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700424/real-part-of-complex-number)

Comment: @RonakShah this exactly what i want , Thanks